# Java regex, find a specific key : value with digits, with or without comma separated

Tags: java, regex

I need to fetch a retrieve a particular value from a key named **'Result'** found on text files.

A Text could look like this

This is text file :

> value 1: abc
>
> value 2: def
>
> value 3: xyz
>
> value 3: Constant : **Result:482,9** abc²:88,55 r:0
>
> ```
>            x = abc  in Pa ,  y = eee in yyy
> ```

I need to get the value of the key : Result, which is in this case **482,9**

This is my pseudo code:

```
     private static final String resultRegex = "(K:(?<Result>\\d+,\\d+).*)";
     private final Pattern RESULT_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(resultRegex);
     
     Matcher resultMatcher = RESULT_PATTERN.matcher(fileContent);
        String resultValue = "";
        if (resultMatcher.find()) {
            resultValue = resultMatcher.group(RESULT_REGEX_VALUE);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(EXCEPTION_FILE_RESULT_NOT_VALID);
        }
```

This works and gives me **482,9** as result.
But It doesn't work when the value in the result doesn't have comma and is of Integer type.

Any suggestions how to change :

> ```
> private static final String resultRegex = "(Result:(?<Result>\\d+,\\d+).*)";
> ```

Comment: You can use: `\\d*,?\\d+`

Comment: anubhava ,thanks it works. Any suggestion if the float number has a dot '.' instead of a comma? ','  ?

Comment: Then use: `\\d*[,.]?\\d+`

Comment: Thanks, it worked

Comment: `\\d+(?:[,\\.]\\d+)?` will be more accurate. It finds integer or float value only.

About: `\\d*[,.]?\\d+` solution. `.` is any symbol, `\\.` is a dot. It will match `,123`, `a123`, `123a123`, etc.

Comment: @Sergey, you should read more about [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html): most of the special chars lose their special meaning inside `[...]`. A dot inside `[.]` matches a *literal* dot.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, wow, tnx.. it's really usefull and new information for me )

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to extract a floating number after `Result:`, and perhaps, got confused with the named capture group usage. Actually, the name here does not make any difference, you might as well use a numbered group, but what is important is the `K:` in the pattern: it requires the next pattern to match after a sequence of chars `K:`. And that is not the case here.

You may match the number after `Result:`:

```
private static final String resultRegex = "Result:\\s*(?<Result>\\d+[,.]\\d+)";
private static final Pattern RESULT_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(resultRegex);
```

Here, `Result:\s*(?<Result>\d+[,.]\d+)` pattern matches `Result:`, 0+ whitespaces (`\s*`), and then captures into group "Result" 1 or more digits, a comma or period, and again 1 or more digits.

See a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/OfWKhp) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DWklww/1).

```
String fileContent = "value 1: abc\n\nvalue 2: def\n\nvalue 3: xyz\n\nvalue 3: Constant : Result:482,9 abc²:88,55 r:0\n\n           x = abc  in Pa ,  y = eee in yyy";
Matcher resultMatcher = RESULT_PATTERN.matcher(fileContent);
String resultValue = "";
if (resultMatcher.find()) {
    resultValue = resultMatcher.group("Result");
} else {
    throw new RuntimeException(EXCEPTION_FILE_RESULT_NOT_VALID);
}
System.out.println(resultValue); // => 482,9
```